# AngularJS: Bind scope to REST retrieved iframe

Tags: angularjs, iframe, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, angular-http

I have a form to modify my scope. This scope is then used to update a another part in my website.
That part, I would now like to put in a separate (template) file and dynamically load into an iframe.

The Iframe is working if I provide static HTML to it, but I can't get it to run with loading another file as template.

This is my current code:

```
cvFormApp.directive('cvframe', function($compile, $http, appConfig) {
  $http({
    url: appConfig.baseUrl + 'res/templates/classic.html',
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
    tpl = response.data;
  });

  return function($scope, $element, tpl) {

    var $body = angular.element($element[0].contentDocument.body),
      template = $compile('<h1>The date in the iframe is {{date}}</h1>')($scope);
    $body.append(template);
  };
});
```

How do I get the referenced classic.html to be inserted into the iframe and binded to the rest of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want. I think you messing with the ansync response as you are loading the template asynchronously using `$http` call. You should have include append that template from the `$http` success.

**Directive**

```
cvFormApp.directive('cvframe', function($compile, $http, appConfig) {
    return function($scope, $element, tpl) {
      $http({
        url: appConfig.baseUrl + 'res/templates/classic.html',
        method: 'GET'
      }).then(function(response) {
        var $body = angular.element($element[0].contentDocument.body), 
                    template = response.data;
        $body.append($compile(template)(scope)); //appended compiled element to DOM
      });
    };
});
```

Comment: Great, that works. But somehow, it is not compiling the loaded content. It is being left with lots of {{variables}} instead of binding it to the scope.

Comment: you need to compile the template variable with current scope..will make it working..

Comment: That made it! Thank you.

Comment: @nogga Glad to help you..Thanks :)